# How to have multiple angular apps in a single webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have recently played with Angular and I don't know where to start with linking multiple external, html, applications into a single html document.

If this isn't clear enough let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already created the angular apps and that the main  modules for the 2 (assuming 2) different apps are `myApp1` and `myApp2`, the following should work:

```
<!-- index.html (or whatever the page is called) -->
<html>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp1">...</div>
    <div ng-app="myApp2" id="app2>...</div>

    <script ...> <!-- script(s) that include the sources of the apps -->
    <script>
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"),['myApp2']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED:
The second app will have to be bootstrapped in code.

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/eHXulGQNsvjy7WCAJwqg?p=preview

Comment: The second `ng-app` would not be initiated.

Comment: @Joy Please see my update. And here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/eHXulGQNsvjy7WCAJwqg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One option and probably the easiest one is to use two Iframes.

You can have each app load all of its external dependencies without having to worry about conflicts.